# Object's push method not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a object for which i am using push method and it gives me length one more than expected.

```
   var Object=[];
   var temp = {};
   var j=0;
   while(j<2){
      temp.id= j+1;
      //other properties setting

      Object.push(temp);
      j++;
  }

console.log(Object.length);
```

gives me 3. Also I see three object values, first as empty second has id =1 and third has id =2.

Comment: `Object` is a constructor.

Comment: Where did you define the variable `Object`?

Comment: No such thing as the `.push` method on an Object. `.push` is a method of Array. [Reference...](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/t4Ls4/)

Comment: I have object=[] its array.

Answer (score 2):

`.push` is a function of `Array` and not `Object` and don't use variable names that cause ambiguity.

Use:

```
var arr = [];
var temp = {};
var j = 0;
while (j < 2) {
    temp.id = j + 1;
    //other properties setting

    arr.push(temp);
    j++;
}

console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: Object represents array in my case. Its for placeholder i write Object.